# Making an numpy array subclass where all shape changing operations return a normal array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an array subclass, where some of the extra attributes are only valid for the object's original shape.  Is there a way to make sure that all array shape changing operations return a normal numpy array instead of an instance of my class?

I've already written array_wrap, but this doesn't seem to have any effect on operations like `np.mean`, `np.sum` or `np.rollaxis`.  These all just return an instance of my class.

```
import numpy as np    

class NewArrayClass(np.ndarray):
    __array_priority__ = 3.0
    def __array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context=None):
        if out_arr.shape == self.shape:
            out = out_arr.view(new_array)
            # Do a bunch of class dependant initialization and attribute copying.
            # ...
            return out
        else:
            return np.asarray(out_arr)

A = np.arange(10)
A.shape = (5, 2)
A = arr.view(NewArrayClass)
# Would like this to be np.ndarray, but get new_array_class.
print type(np.sum(A, 0))
```

I figure I have to do something in `__new__` or `__array_finalize__`, but I haven't a clue what.

**Update:**
After carefully reading the numpy documentation on subclassing (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html), all array shape changing operations are doing the 'new from template' operation.  So the question becomes, how do you make the 'new from template' operation return ndarray instances instead of instances of my class.  As far as I can tell, `__new__` is never called within these functions.

**Alternative:**
Assuming the above is not possible, how do I at least identify in `__array_finalize__` the new from template operation (as opposed to view casting)?  This would at least let me dereference some attributes that are copied by reference.  I could also set a flag or something telling the new instance that its shape is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not introducing any new members to your `NewArrayClass` instances, you can reassign the `__class__` attribute of the returned instances.

```
A.__class__ = np.ndarray
```

The point is why would you like to do such a thing. Do you engage in strict type checking elsewhere? You'd go far more with duck typing.

Comment: I have a bunch of methods in my class that will raise an exception if the array is the wrong shape.  I want to make these methods inaccessible.

Comment: So the method described may work for you. The methods introduced by `NewArrayClass` will not apply in any way to the instance with modified `__class__`.

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to do this with classes that are defined in C extensions, such as `np.ndarray`. I get `TypeError: __class__ assignment: only for heap types`.